# Dynamic css classes back to top

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to hook into an event on scroll in amp to reveal a simple back-to-top button. I was hoping to find something under amp-dynamic-css-classes. How are others achieving this please.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks I am an avid reader of SO and a an experienced developer. The folks at Amp (google) are inviting us over hear to ask these type of questions. A back to top button is trivial in non-amp apps. I am asking how people are getting around this in amp. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, but this GitHub issue which is actively being worked on has the solution for your problem: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/8411